# How to find out number of files currently open by Java application?

Tags: java

Suppose a lot of what your application does deals with reading contents of files. It goes without saying that files that are opened then closed and life is good unless ... new files come in faster then old files get closed. This is the pickle of a situation I found myself in.

Now, is there a way to reliably know how many files are opened by the process? Something that is as reliable as looking at `ls /proc/my_pid/fd | wc -l` from inside the JVM?

I suspect the answer may be OS-specific, so let me add that I am running Java on Linux.

Comment: Can't you just increment a count whenever you open a file...and decrement it whenever you close one?

Comment: I suppose that's one way of doing it .. Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: You could execute that command in java. Have a look:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

I cannot imagine that java memorizes which and how many files you have opened.

Comment: I guess the simplest way is just .... to check how many entries can be found in `/proc/self/fd/`. That's what the [proc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) filesystem is for: Get (and set) process information at runtime. _hierarchical tree of values with node-dependent read/write semantics + mapping of the same into the hierarchical tree of streams that is a filesystem = unified win_ (well, in a typeless Plan 9 kind of way - even better: open a JDBC conn to "somewhere" then query/update sys & proc using SQL, a bit like [OSQuery](https://osquery.io/) but far more complete)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

On Unix, one way is using the [`ManagementFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html) to get the [`OperatingSystemMxBean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html) and if it is a [`UnixOperatingSystemMXBean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/extension/com/sun/management/UnixOperatingSystemMXBean.html), you can use the `getOpenFileDescriptorCount()` method.

Example code:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;
import com.sun.management.UnixOperatingSystemMXBean;

public class OpenFileCount{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        OperatingSystemMXBean os = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
        if(os instanceof UnixOperatingSystemMXBean){
            System.out.println("Number of open fd: " + ((UnixOperatingSystemMXBean) os).getOpenFileDescriptorCount());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does performing this task by itself increase number of FD?

Comment: Does not seem to. Thanks. This is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @FDinoff Great answer! Any idea on how to try this behavior in Windows?

Answer (score 12):

If you want to get the number of `ls /proc/my_pid/fd | wc -l` in java, you could use **JMX**.

When you have `MBeanServerConnection`, you can get attribute "`OpenFileDescriptorCount`". this will give you the same result as the above `ls..|wc -l`.

also there is another attribute "`MaxFileDescriptorCount`", which tells your the max count allowed.

If you just want to know the value, but not getting it in your code, you could either do your `ls..|wc -l` way, or read from `jconsole` (with GUI).

**NOTE**

```
ls /proc/my_pid/fd | wc -l
```

this number indicates how many fd opened by your process(java application). e.g. your business files are counted, also those jars, libraries files are counted too. If you just want to get the count of your business files, you have to implement a counter by yourself. Or, say you want to do it with shellscript, `grep` something out then `wc -l`

**EDIT**

add code example, but it is just an example. not written in IDE, not tested with compiler. :)

```
ObjectName oName = new ObjectName("java.lang:type=OperatingSystem");
MBeanServerConnection conn ; // you should get the connection following the api, take a look the java api/ google some example
javax.management.AttributeList list = conn.getAttributes(oName, new String[]{"OpenFileDescriptorCount", "MaxFileDescriptorCount"});
for(Attribute attr: list.asList()){
    System.out.println(attr.getName() + ": " + attr.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For the sake of completing/adding to the answer:

Many people uses LSOF in Linux based system to monitor file descriptors and their details. However LSOF lists all kind of FDs(CWD,MEM) which is not returned by UnixOperatingSystemMXBean.getOpenFileDescriptorCount().

Details can be found in http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-lsof.html
This may cause some confusion.

To clarify UnixOperatingSystemMXBean.getOpenFileDescriptorCount() only shows application opened files descriptors.
But LSOF (lsof -a -p ) lists other file descriptors opened by kernel on behalf of the process.

To list only application level FDS one can filter out other type of FDs

lsof -a -p yourprocid -d ^txt,^mem,^cwd,^rtd,^DEL

Comment: This answer has the benefit of working on macOS as well.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for necroposting, but guys, you're ignoring -K option of lsof cause java have threads, each of them have their own FD that are living in /proc/$PID/tasks/fd/

and there is A HUGE difference:

```
root@xxx:/root# lsof -p 13553 | wc -l
612
root@xxx:/root# lsof -p 13553 -K | wc -l
112108
```

Comment: Not sure if its my OS, but if you use `-K` argument it will report the files opened in all processes. So if I do: `lsof -p <non existant PID> -K | wc -l` outputs the same as `lsof | wc -l`. Only without `-K` seems to work as expected.

Comment: -K option gives a number of open descriptors for all process tasks. Useful when your process spawn a bunch of subprocesses live java applications do

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu, the below `lsof` command works

```
sudo lsof -c java
```

Answer (score 2):

Better than *counting* the open files is *listing* them, and *why* they were opened (and never closed, or closed only by garbage collection). https://github.com/jenkinsci/lib-file-leak-detector can do this (in a non-production environment).